# How to define a function that invokes ggplot2 functions and takes a variable name among its arguments?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As an example, suppose that I have this snippet of code:

```
binwidth <- 0.01
my.histogram <- ggplot(my.data, aes(x = foo, fill = type)) +
                geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth,
                               aes(y = ..density..),
                               position = "identity",
                               alpha = 0.5) +
                lims(x = c(0 - binwidth, 1 + binwidth), y = c(0, 100)) +
                labs(x = "foo", y = "density")
```

Further, suppose that `my.data` has many other columns besides `foo` that could be plotted using pretty much the same code.  Therefore, I would like to define a helper function `make.histogram`, so that I could replace the assignment above with something like:

```
my.histogram <- make.histogram(foo, bindwidth = 0.01)
```

Actually, this looks a bit weird to me.  Would R complain that `foo` is not defined?  Maybe the call would have to be this instead:

```
my.histogram <- make.histogram("foo", binwidth = 0.01)
```

Be that as it may, how would one define `make.histogram`?

For the purpose of this question, `make.histogram` may treat `my.data` as a global variable.

Also, note that in the snippet above, `foo` appears twice, once (as a variable) as the `x` argument in the first `aes` call, and once (as a string) as the `x` argument in the `labs` call.  In other words, the `make.histogram` functions needs somehow to translate the column specified in its first argument into both a variable name and a string.

Comment: You could do this using R's non-standard evaluation features. There's a good description of how they work in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: @andrew.punnett: Thanks for the pointer!  I posted an answer based on what I learned from it.

Comment: I hope I haven't led you down a dark path!

Comment: @andrew.punnett: Oh, it is dark, all right!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the material that @andrew.punnett linked in his comment, it was very easy to code the desired function:

```
make.histogram <- function(column.name, binwidth = 0.02) {

    base.aes <- eval(substitute(aes(x = column.name, fill = type)))
    x.label <- deparse(substitute(column.name))

    ggplot(my.data, base.aes) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth,
                   aes(y = ..density..),
                   position = "identity",
                   alpha = 0.5) +
    lims(x = c(0 - binwidth, 1 + binwidth), y = c(0, 100)) +
    labs(x = x.label, y = "density")

}

my.histogram <- make.histogram(foo, binwidth = 0.01)
```

The benefit of this solution is its generality:  it relies only on base R functions (`substitute`, `eval`, and `deparse`), so it can be easily ported to situations outside of the `ggplot2` context.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure to understand your question.

Why couldn't you use `aes_string()` and define a function like below ?

```r
make.histogram <- function(variable) { 
  p <- ggplot(my.data, aes_string(x = variable, fill = "type")) + (...) + xlab(variable)
  print(p)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ggplot is part of the *tidyverse*, I think *tidyeval* will come in handy:

```
make.histogram <- function(var = "foo", bindwith = 0.01) {
        varName <- as.name(var)
        enquo_varName <- enquo(varName)
        ggplot(my.data, aes(x = !!enquo_varName, fill = type)) +
        ...
        labs(x = var)
}
```

Basically, with `as.name()` we generate a name object that matches `var` (here var is a string like "foo"). Then, following [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), we use `enquo()` to look at that name and return the associated value as a *quosure*. This quosure can then be unquoted inside the `ggplot()` call using `!!`.